# How to handle FileUpload using selenium-Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
//div[@id='upload_button']
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='upload_button']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='upload_button']")).sendKeys("V://Images//CSV/text.csv");
```

- I have a upload button in my browser
- written a script that will click the button and send the mentioned file from given path
- Here it is selecting the Upload button and file explorer opening
- Not opening path, to send the csv file

Comment: Do you see this `//input[@type='file']` xpath at least 1 time in your HTML-DOM?

Comment: yes it is exist

Comment: But not highlighting upload button

Comment: <div id="upload_button">
                            <label>
                                <input id="Input" type="file" accept=".txt,.csv">
                                <span id="noFile">Upload
                                    CSV</span>
                                <span class="icon  icon-upload"></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

Comment: Got it, it does not matter if it is highlighting or not, check out the below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `//input[@type='file']` is present at least one time in the `HTML-DOM`, the you can directly send the keys, you do not need to

1. Click on upload button
2. Select file using explorer
3. and upload the file.

This feature was introduced in one of the Selenium 3 versions.

**Effective code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("V://Images//CSV/text.csv");
```

I would recommend that use explicit wait for more stability.

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElemnt(By.xpath("//input[@type='file'])).sendKeys(" give source file path");

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).